# How to hide your valuables in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

People are always stealing my diamonds and other hard-to-find items. How can I hide them well enough to be sure no-one would steal them while I'm exploring? I've seen some ideas but none of them seemed to work. Are there any traps or other stuff that might help?

Edit: It's a vanilla server without any OPs (except the admin of course).

Comment: go to another server where steeling isn't allowed

Comment: I realise this question is old, but the issue is very much recurring. Nowadays, there are multiple, incredibly creative ways to hide your chests :) [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=minecraft+hide+my+chest)!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Place your valuables in an [Ender Chest](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Ender_Chest). Each player has their own Ender Chest space, so if someone would look in the Ender Chest you've put your diamonds in, they only see their own stuff they have put in an Ender Chest.

Comment: One thing to note however is that Ender Chests will only be able to store one small chest worth of your valuables, so keep it to just that.

Comment: ... or one small chest worth of Shulker Boxes worth of your valuables, as of 1.9

Answer (score 2):

Another suggestion is to have an underground base, and store your items in droppers. This makes it hard to find your base for people with hacks like X-ray and chestfinder, which lights up chests. A dropper is moderately efficient as it has 9 slots and can be crafted with seven cobblestone plus one redstone dust.

Comment: People with hacks such as those can configure to also show up dispensers besides chests. Rule of thumb: if it is in the open, it can be accessed, no matter what you try. Remember that you yourself have to access the chest. In this regard the Ender Chest seems to be the best option, as it's a per-user space.

Comment: The Ender Chest is obviously the best solution, but for more than 27 slots of space, this seems to be the best method. Only some clients include selective X-ray.

Answer (score 0):

You can always store your valuables with you. That way, you will only lose them if you die or if someone manages to enter your account.

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious way to hide things is with false walls/ceilings/floors.  Assuming no one is using an x-ray hack, you can easily hide away a chest or two behind wood planks, which are easy to remove by hand, with a space open above the chest so you can open it without further destroying the area.

The best hiding place for such chests is in a ceiling, since few people will look up when trying to find your secret stash.  If you build your home into a cave, simply build a roof, then place a chest above that roof and leave the area above it unmined.

For a secret chest less likely to be stumbled upon by entrepreneurial roof-builders, you can create walls in your building, and simply leave an empty space in one of your walls for a chest to be hidden in (a corner where four walls meet is ideal, since you can build two walls leading into the corner, leave a space open above it to access the chest, and not have any part of your secret stash revealed to a casual observer).

All of this of course is vulnerable to someone running in and tearing your entire building apart for your rare loot, so an Ender Chest is still the best place for incredibly rare materials.  For slightly less rare materials though, this secret chest will do.

Answer (score -1):

the trick is build your roof of cobble stone then place one furnace and it looks like cobble stone and you can put 2 things in it works for me

Comment: I don't see how this would work. Cobblestone looks nothing like a furnace. Do you perhaps mean smooth stone?